# Animate the parenting of an object

Tags: rigging, bones, constraints

let's say we have a magazine, a gun, and hands.

The magazine is parented with the gun. When I make an animation of reloading, I want the Magazine to be a parent of the hand, then after the magazine goes back into the gun I want the magazine to be parented with the gun again.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use two *Child of* constraint with an animated influences:

[image]

In the above gif, there are two animated empties. The cube follows `Empty` first, then switches to `Empty.001`.

Comment: Sorry i dont understand... could you explain again please?

Comment: Oh , the thing is - all the bones are one , so the gun and all the parts are just one rig , not different objects

Comment: Glad you got it working :) Just in case anyone else is reading, you can use these constraints on individual bones too, but you need to be in pose mode.