# Parent bone temporarily?

Tags: animation, armature, rigging, constraints

I asked a [similar question before](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8959/599), except this time instead of parenting objects I want to parent the gun magazine bone to the left arms wrist for a bit, then set it back to the gun bones.

My arms and my gun are all one armature, so I only have one armature in the scene.

Comment: What about using a *child of* bone constraint? BTW, [tags like "gun" and "clip" aren't really good blender-related tags](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags)..

Comment: All i see is "Child of" And then i can only use objects , i dont see "Child of bone"

Comment: OH ... FOund it ....lol

Comment: It's in the *Bone constraints* section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same technique as [before](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8959/599), but using a bone constraint.

The only difference is that you must add the constraint from *Properties > Bone constraints* panel instead of the *Constraints* panel, while in *pose mode*:

[image]