# Removing Parent (Bone relative) but keeping animation

Tags: animation, bones, unity

I made a reload animation for a game that I am making. So far the animation looks great. To make the gun stay in the hand, I made the gun a relative parent to the wrist bone.

Now that the animation is finished, I want to remove the parent from the gun, but keep the animation. I tried Using 
-Animation 
 -bake action 
  -clear parent

but that did not keep that wrist animation.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a solution to my problem, but I did find a great alternative. Looking at another question I learned that constraints would be much better for parenting in an animation.

Link to other question here: [Animate the parenting of an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8959/animate-the-parenting-of-an-object?rq=1)

Hope this helps anyone else with a similar problem