# Objects move together But not all time

Tags: objects, armature, bones

i have a project. i am doing my robotic arm with blender. i have a one robotic arm and one box. i need to take box with arm to move and rotate. i have a bone system in robotic arm. But i can't move together arm and box. I try to do group(crtl+G) but it is not working and i did try parent object(ctrl+P) again i can't do this. how can i do this? 
i did a Gif for you:   [enter link description here](https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-1ce0294de7.gif)

Comment: You can use **Child of** constrains and play with the influence using keyframes in it. An exemple here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8959/animate-the-parenting-of-an-object

Comment: Yes this is right answer thank you. but i want to show you smomething look at this:  https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-813d6668a9.gif

Comment: Ok ok Thank a lot for information. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsdRUk807qk 
thank you very much